# partial differential equation change of coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, chain-rule

$$y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = c(x, y, u)$$ Express it in terms of $w(r,\theta) = u(r\cos\theta, r\cos\theta)$, $r$ and $\theta$.

I have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \cos\theta\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \sin\theta\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}$$

So, the pde becomes

$$r\sin\theta\cos\theta\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} - \frac{r\sin^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} - r\cos\theta\sin\theta\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} - \frac{r\cos^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} = c(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, w(r,\theta))$$

Which reduces to:

$$-\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} = c(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, w(r,\theta))$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $\large\color{green}\checkmark$

Taking the [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664526/partial-differentiation-change-of-coordinates) in matrix form:

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\\\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-r\sin(\theta)&r\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Applying matrix inversion produces:  $$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-r\sin(\theta)&r\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\\\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial\theta}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)/r\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)/r\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial r}\\\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial\theta}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

As you had.  Substitution then leads to your final result.  So it all checks out.